# Disable cache on a block

Tags: cache, header, block-cache

Out of despair, I ask question here.

I have a phtml (top_links.phtml) file that is cached when I am not logged in but not cached when I am logged in. I need it to be never cached as I display the geolocation there.

I tried

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks',false); ?>
```

in the `header.phtml`

I tried

```
<block type="page/html" name="top.links2" as="topLinks" template="page/html/top_links.phtml"> 
            <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_lifetime</key></action>
            <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_tags</key></action>
        </block>
```

in my layout.xml

I tried to do as recommended [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499394/disable-caching-for-some-files-in-magento).

none worked. Then I realized that when logged in, it is not cached...

Can somebody give me some pointers?

Thanks already

Comment: Did you try `<action method="setCacheLifetime"><time>null</time></action>`?

Comment: I will try that

Comment: tried it at no avail, I as well tried `<time>0</time>`, no luck neither...

Answer (score 3):

Start by identifying the block class instance by

```
var_dump(get_class_name($this))
```

Within the phtml file.

Then in the block (either by extending it if core, or editing it if local/community), define the cache lifetime.

There's three main (magic getter/setter) important functions used when Magento evaluates if a block is cacheable.

- `getCacheLifetime()`
- `getCacheKeyInfo`
- `getCacheTags`

I say functions, but these are just the return methods for the `$_data` variables, so you could define the data in the block constructor.

Similarly, you can do this in your XML for a cleaner approach.

```
<action method="setCacheLifetime" />
```

I'll be honest and say I've never tried to set a null lifetime for a block in XML so I'm not fully sure if it will work, but it certainly works in the block class return method/constructor.

Be sure to set the lifetime to null - using 0 will still create a cache entry with 0 lifetime (thus filling your cache with thousands of surplus, unused cache entries).

Comment: Thanks for your help, It is not a block per se that I am trying not to cache but a template phtml. I do not see how to implement the 3 functions. I also tried the XML solution, that is not giving me any result.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to go here is using for example https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_TemplateHints to identify the cached block/template.
Sometimes its not the one Block, but one of the parent Blocks, which cache the containing blocks together.

The linked tool can show you if a block is cached or not and also gives some infos about it like block name, type, template, cache key and similar.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact answer you're looking for but it's what I did in a similar situation. 
I had an issue before requiring this block (and a few more) to be removed from cache when using Varnish. Due to various problems I found it easier to just remove the block from the layout completely and display it via an Ajax call after the page had loaded.

To do this I created a mini module (controller, layout and template file). In the layout I referenced the block and called it in the template. Using ajax then I called the url and appended it to an appropriate div.

Also when logged in it may need to be uncached as there could be a risk of displaying incorrect duplicate data to multiple users.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is indeed not what I am looking for as I want to keep our existing code (running rather well except that).

Comment: Also, one question, how come the HTML served by AJAX is not cached? is that because you request a different "page" each time?

Comment: Basically (as far as I understand) the page is cached, not the actual code. So while the html from the ajax load appears on the page, the actual markup is not part of the page.